# Как совмещать php и javascript?

Tags: веб-программирование

Я хочу сделать на сайте простую форму **авторизации**, которая будет при нажатии на кнопку, сравнивать данные введённые в 2 формочки `<input>`(пароль и логин) с таблицей из базы данных **MySQL** .
Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне изучать ?
Для программирования кнопки, использую **Javascript**, для подключения к базе данных **MySQL** и получения данных из таблицы использую **php**.
Не могу понять как связать php и javascript, пробовал читать про использование **AJAX** и **Node.js**, но там все запутанно и не понятно.

php:
connect.php:

```
<?php
    $host = ' ';
    $user = ' ';
    $pass = ' '; //
    $db_name = ' ';   // Имя базы данных

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name); // Соединяемся с базой

    $login = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT username FROM `users`');
    $password = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT pass FROM `users`');

    
?>
```

javascript:
script.js:

```
function onclickLogin() {
    var login = document.getElementById('login')
    var password = document.getElementById('password')
    
    
}
```

html:
index.html:

```
<head>

      <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<form method="get" action="connect.php">
      <div class="panel" style="display: block;">
          <h1>Авторизация</h1>
          <input id="login" class="login" name="logim" type="text" placeholder="Введите логин">
          <input id="password" name="password" class="password" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
          <button type="sumbit" name="submit" onclick="onclickLogin()" class="loginButton">Авторизоваться</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140074/discussion-on-question-by-nastystuffy---php--javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, что информации по подобным задачам полно с хорошими примерами, сделать это можно несколькими способами, можно через `ajax` можно через `submit` формы.

Опишу вкратце, что нужно делать во втором случае:

1. Создаем скрипт php, к примеру `auth.php`, он должен возвращать страницу с формой и скриптом, например для валидации полей перед отправкой формы, а так же будет возвращать защищенное содержимое, либо делать редирект на другие защищенные страницы.
2. В теге формы авторизации в аттрибуте `"action"` нужно указать `auth.php` и выбрать `method="post"` в качестве метода отправки ([method](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method) предпочтительней все делать через `post` - у него меньше ограничений и он безопаснее)
3. при нажатии `submit` можно сделать предварительную валидацию, для этого необходимо передать функцию обработчик атрибуту формы `onsubmit` таким образом: `onsubmit="submitHandler(event)"` именно указание `event` в скобках позволит сделать `event.preventDefault()` что пригодится для отмены отправки формы и предотвратит перезагрузку страницы с потерей уже введенных данных.
4. Если проверка пройдена идет оправка формы где скрипт `auth.php` вызывается снова, проверяя в самом начале наличие  переменной в сессии например `$_SESSION['user_id']` при наличиии которой можно смело отрисовывать защищенный контент, или делать редирект на другие страницы.
5. При отстутсвии переменной сессии мы должны извлечь поля переданные методом `post` в соответсвующем массиве `$_POST`,
   сделать запрос в базу данных, при успешном прохождении проверок можем вывести защищенный контент страницы или сделать редирект на другие страницы, заодно задавая `$_SESSION['user_id']`, чтобы при перезагрузке страницы не выводить форму авторизации снова.
6. Если авторизация была провалена выводим снова форму для авторизации.

Перед тем как вы соберетесь хранить пароли в БД советую ознакомиться c
[Безопасное хеширование паролей](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php)

файл ниже демонстрирует:

- валидацию полей до отправки на сервер (на заполнение и т.п.)
- авторизацию (для входа пароль и логин **admin**)
- разлогирование

код прокомментирован

файл `auth.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  php session_start(); // начинаем сессию (чтобы использовать массив сессии) 
  // функция выводит содержимое страницы для авторизовавшися пользователей
  function getAuthContent(){
    echo '<h1>Авторизация пройдена успешно</h1>';
    $form = <<<EOD
      <form id="auth" method="post" action="auth.php">
        <input type="text" name="logout" value="logout" hidden>
        <button type="sumbit">Выйти</button>
      </form>
    EOD;
    echo "$form";  
    exit(); 
  }

  // разлогирование
  if (isset($_POST['logout'])){ 
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']); 
  }
    
  // если есть id пользователь уже залогинился  
  if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){ 
    getAuthContent(); 
  }  

  // проверка на валидность логина и пароля
  // тут самое время использовать базу данных
  if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'] )){
    $user = $_POST['login'];
    $pass = $_POST['password']; 
    if ($user == 'admin' && $pass == 'admin'){
      // запоминаем id пользователя или что-то другое
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = 42; 
      getAuthContent();

    }
  }
  // иначе выводим форму авторизации
    $form = <<<EOD
      <script>
        function onclickLogin(event) {
            const  login = document.getElementById('login')
            const  password = document.getElementById('password')
            const  form = document.getElementById('auth')
            if ( login.value.trim() === '' || password.value.trim() === ''){
              event.preventDefault()
              alert('Заполните все поля!')
            }
        }
      </script>
      <form id="auth" method="post" action="auth.php" onsubmit="onclickLogin(event)">
        <div class="panel" style="display: block;">
          <h1>Авторизация</h1>
          <input id="login" class="login" name="login" type="text" placeholder="Введите логин">
          <input id="password" name="password" class="password" type="password" placeholder="Введите пароль">
          <button type="sumbit">Авторизоваться</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    EOD;
    echo "$form";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Да, зачем нам сессии, если всё можно хранить в кукисах.

Comment: Что значит рисовать форму авторизации?

Comment: @NastyStuffy  echo "<form>"

Comment: @InDevX, можно и сессиями, было бы желание)

Answer (score 1):

При объявлении формы на странице мы указываем вот такие вот штуки, метод, которым будет отправляться форма либо get либо post, и action  - место куда будет вся эта форма передаваться
`<form method = "get/post" action ="php файл в котором будет происходить обработка данных и работа с бд">`
Вот мы форму заполнили и отправили. Затем в файле, который мы указали в action, в зависимости от метода, который мы указали, мы достаем наши данные из массива(либо $_GET либо $_POST) и что-то с ними делаем(проверяем, сохраняем в бд и.т.д)

Comment: А если у меня отдельная кнопка которая проверяет input с помощью js скрипта, мне создавать форму для кнопки или для всего div (в div находится: кнопка, заголовок, и input`ы ?

Comment: Вот так вот форма должна выглядеть
`<form method ="" action = "">
<input>
<input>
<input type="submit">`//кнопка
`</form>`